# how can i pass java object from server side to client side

Tags: java, spring, web-services, object, server

can i pass java POJO class object to client side .

for example user send request to server **"/user"**. server should  send response as **User.java** object

User.java class is

```
public class User {

private String name = null;
private String education = null;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getEducation() {
    return education;
}
public void setEducation(String education) {
    this.education = education;
}
```

}

Comment: You can serialize your class to Json text and transfer it to client, then deserialize it to class.

Comment: Or you can you "plain old Java serialization" to directly transport your java objects as byte streams.

Comment: With "plain old Java serialization", how can the Client cast the Object back to POJO? They won't have the POJO class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two simple ways that I can think of:

1. Use JAXB to convert the User object into an xml and back to transfer the data between client and server.
2. Use GSON/Jackson to do the same with a JSON.

Either ways the XML/JSON will directly map to your Objects and are fairly easy to implement.

There are other ways but I assume that you are using a web service and these are best suited for it.

Comment: exactly @Dunxton .., i am using  RESTful webservice

Answer (score 1):

As mr.icetea suggested you can serialize the java object to json and then pass it . You can do the serialization/deserialization using the jackson library : http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways:

1. You can use any of the JSON,XML,SOAP formats.
2. Or you can use applet
3. Rmi if using standalone java client.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same requirement, I used servlet to do that. If you can use servlet, you can take this reference.

Servlet side

```
ObjectInputStream objectStream = new ObjectInputStream(request.getInputStream());
User user = (User) objectStream.readObject();
objectStream .close();
```

Client side

```
User user = new User();
urlConnectionToTarget.setRequestMethod("POST");
urlConnectionToTarget.setDoOutput(true);
urlConnectionToTarget.setDoInput(true);
urlConnectionToTarget.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
urlConnectionToTarget.connect();
ObjectOutputStream servletObjectStream = new ObjectOutputStream(urlConnectionToTarget.getOutputStream());
servletObjectStream.writeObject(user);
servletObjectStream.flush();
servletObjectStream.close();
```

Comment: messageObjectStram object belogns to which class @Pasupathi